# Почему dereference переводят как разыменование?

Tags: c++, c

Пример кода:

```
int x = 10;
int *p = &x; // reference - получение адреса объекта x
int y = *p;  // dereference - получение объекта по указателю p
```

Во многих книгах на русском при переводе dereference используют термин "разыменовать". Насколько я понимаю значение слова "разыменование" - это лишение имени. Но тут вроде никого имени не лишают.

Другой вариант перевода который мне встречался - "снятие косвенности". Этот вариант уже ближе по смыслу к оригиналу.

Так почему же "разыменование"?

Comment: IMHO, у вас в комментариях всё явно описано. А всё остальное (во всяком случае про C) - словоблудие.

Comment: @PinkTux Ну т.е. перевод разыменование - некорректный с точки зрения значения слова в русском языке?

Comment: Почему? Разыменование - Превращение имени во что-то другое, вроде логично.

Comment: Dereference - взять значение ячейки косвенным способом, через указатель. Термин "разыменование" вызывает у меня неприятие. Непонятно, почему до сих пор бытует этот термин. Кто-то один лингвистически неподкованный сделал корявый перевод, он попал во все учебники, и теперь мы должны его использовать. Точно так же ужасен термин "возвращает". Функция возвращает... Возвращать - это отдать то, что взял. А функция выдает результат работы программы, а не то, что взяла. Тоже, все привыкли, никто внимания уже не обращает, а новичкам режет ухо.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

На самом деле - перевод совершенно правильный. Смотрите, что получается:

Любой объект в любом языке программирования состоит из двух неразрывных сущностей:

1. Значения (что бы мы под этим не понимали)
2. Имени этого значения

Во многих языках программирования типа С различие между этими сущностями не подчёркивается. Так например, во многих языках можно написать нечто вроде:

```
a := a + 7;
```

Здесь одна и та же лексема "а" используется в разных смыслах. Справа - как значение, слева - как имя. Начинающие программисты зачастую этого не осознают.
В некоторых языках это различие делается явным. Например, в языке Shell имя переменной может быть "A", а значение - "${A}".

Возвращаясь к Вашему вопросу. Во многих языках программирования существует особый тип переменных, значениями которых являются **имена** других переменных. Ведь что такое ссылка (указатель) ? Это машинный адрес - имя ячейки, содержащей значение.

Поэтому "разыменовать" означает - сказать процессору, что **значение** данной переменной надо превратит  в **имя** некоторой другой переменной. Вот так:

```
int a;
int *pa = &a;

a = 3;
*pa = a + 4;
```

Результат довольно очевиден. А на самом деле, мы сказали процессору, что:

- Хотя *pa* стоит слева от знака присваивания, но её имя нас не интересует.
- Нам нужно имя некоторой другой переменной, заданной её значением.
- Фактически, в данном примере имя *pa* изчезает! Она "разыменовывается".

Comment: Спасибо. Объяснения понятные. Пример со значением и именем очень хороший: разыменование - превращение имени в значение. Хотя всё равно получается что слово разыменование не отражает всей глубины происходящего за ним процесса.

Comment: @random, да нет там никакой "глубины", это синтаксический сахар, не более :) Если вы понимаете что такое указатель, то этого достаточно.